# Adding notes to Shapes overlay in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can we add some notes, a string, while making overlay shapes with google maps API? Like If I draw a circle around my home to indicate High alert area within circle with a note on it, so a person seeing the circle will know quickly, or can I just use color scheme to do this? Please, if you guys have some solution?

Comment: This question is currently very unclear, please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.

Such a thing could be achieved with [**InfoWindow class**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow), see also [**InfoWindowOptions object**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) about details what options you can modify
and also check the google documentation [**sample**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#open).

The most important option of the [**InfoWindowOptions object**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) is **content**

> Type:  string|Node
>
> Content to display in the InfoWindow. This can be
>   an **HTML element**, a **plain-text string**, or a **string containing HTML**. The
>   InfoWindow will be sized according to the content. To set an explicit
>   size for the content, set content to be a HTML element with that size.

So let's have a look on how `InfoWindow` is displayed:

- Initialize map ([new google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map))
- Initialize [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)
- Open the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) with the `open()` method

If you want to draw a circle you can use [**Circle class**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle) , see also [**CircleOptions object**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CircleOptions) to see what options you can adjust. It is easy to draw circles on the map - you just need to instantiate a circle(`new google.maps.Circle`) and pass the map in the options object.

Check the following demo code and let me know if something is not clear.

```js
function init() {

  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(33.53625, -111.92674);
  var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p>Beware this is my home :)</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  /*-------------------
    MAP
    -------------------*/
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 13,
    scrollwheel: false
  });

  /*-------------------
    CIRCLE
    -------------------*/
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    map: map,
    center: center,
    radius: 200
  });

  /*-------------------
    INFO WINDOW
    -------------------*/
  var infoWindowIsOpen = true;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    position: center
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
    infoWindowIsOpen = false;
    togglePopupButton.innerHTML = "Show Popup"
  });

  infowindow.open(map);

  /*-------------------
    TOGGLE INFO WINDOW BUTTON
    -------------------*/
  var togglePopupButton = document.getElementById('togglePopup');
  togglePopupButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    infoWindowIsOpen = !infoWindowIsOpen;
    if (infoWindowIsOpen) {
      infowindow.open(map);
      togglePopupButton.innerHTML = 'Hide Popup';
    } else {
      infowindow.close();
      togglePopupButton.innerHTML = 'Show Popup';
    }
  });

}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script async defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=init"></script>

<div id="map" style="width:400px;height:150px;float:left"></div>
<button id="togglePopup" style="float:left">Hide Popup</button>
```